# Save event onclick js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<script>
    var content = document.getElementById('float_content_right');
    var hide = document.getElementById('hide_float_right');
    function hide_float_right() {

        if (content.style.display == "none") {
            content.style.display = "block";
            hide.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:hide_float_right()">Close [X]</a>';

        } else {
            content.style.display = "none";
            hide.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:hide_float_right()">Open...</a>';
        }
    }
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = "<a href='http://phuongnuochoa.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://thegioidoco.net/gif/1.gif'></a>";
    images[1] = "<a href='http://quattran.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://thegioidoco.net/gif/2.gif'></a>";
    images[2] = "<a href='http://dogoducthien.vn' target='_blank'><img src='http://thegioidoco.net/gif/3.gif'></a>";

    $(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]).appendTo('#float_content_right');
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#float_content_right').empty();
        $(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]).appendTo('#float_content_right');
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

And now i want,
When I press the Close button the image is hidden, then F5 again the picture is still hidden. And if I don't press the Close button, then when I F5 the image is still there.

Please help me, this is my exercise!

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` for this.

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o4ptfwdL/ @Maxim

Comment: @Walk how to do it? :(, i know should use localStorage but i can't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session storage in your code. [Like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

On the click of your Close button, set a key in session storage.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('imageVisible', '1');
```

On F5 or page load function call, generally `$(document).ready(function(){})`, you can check this.

```
// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('imageVisible');
if(data == 1)
{
  //show the div containing the image.
}
else
{
  //hide the div containing the image.
}
```